# Encountering unexpected Interlocked behaviour?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, interlocked

I'm writing a web link checker program and encountering behaviour with Interlocked that I can't explain. First, here's an abridged version of the code:

```
public class LinkCheckProcessor
{
    private long _remainingLinks;

    public event EventHandler<LinksCheckedEventArgs> AllLinksChecked;

    private void ProcessLinks(List<Link> links)
    {
        foreach (Link link in links)
        {
            ProcessLink(link);
        }
    }

    private void ProcessLink(Link link)
    {
        var linkChecker = new LinkChecker(link);
        linkChecker.LinkChecked += LinkChecked;
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _remainingLinks);
#if DEBUG
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("LinkChecker: Checking link '{0}', remaining: {1}", link, Interlocked.Read(ref _remainingLinks)));
#endif
        linkChecker.Check();
    }

    void LinkChecked(object sender, LinkCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        var linkChecker = (LinkChecker)sender;

        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _remainingLinks);
#if DEBUG
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("LinkChecker: Checked link '{0}', remaining: {1}", linkChecker.Link, Interlocked.Read(ref _remainingLinks)));
#endif
        if (Interlocked.Read(ref _remainingLinks) == 0)
        {
            OnAllLinksChecked(new LinksCheckedEventArgs(this.BatchId, this.Web.Url));
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm seeing in the debug output are things like:

- LinkChecker: Checked link 'http://serverfault.com', remaining: 1
- LinkChecker: Checked link 'http://superuser.com', remaining: 0
- LinkChecker: Checked link 'http://stackoverflow.com', remaining: -1

I don't understand why (in some code runs) `_remainingLinks` is becoming negative. This is also having the side effect of causing the `AllLinksChecked` event from being fired too early. (By the way, the code above contains the only places that `_remainingLinks` is touched.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Funnily enough, I've never used Interloked.Read - ideally, just capture the return value of Decrement. Still reading, though...

Comment: Is `LinkChecker` your own class?  Is it possible that it's firing off more than one event when checking a single link?

Comment: Btw, do you really have so many links that 32 bits isn't enough?

Comment: I wonder if we need to see The other class, especially the event

Comment: @MarcGravell Using a `long` because Interlocked.Read returns one, although yes I only need an `int`. I can't post the other class because it's my company's IP, but I'll check it for multiple event firings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and propose that `LinkChecker` is firing more than one event for a call to `Check()`.  Short of this, I can't see how the value could possibly go negative.

Comment: I guess that would be plausible if it's a recursive spider.

Comment: Apparently I've been working so hard on this project my eyes are bleeding and I can't read the code or my own debugging messages any more. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your `AllLinksChecked` logic is definitely wrong, since the counter could go `0->1`, `1->0`, `0->1`, `1->0`, `0->1`, `1->0` and thus reach zero multiple times.

But I don't see how the count could ever go negative.  Are these the only places that `_remainingLinks` appears in your code?

---

The first problem could be fixed just by removing the increment code from `ProcessLink` and having `ProcessLinks` initialize the count to `links.Count` before starting the loop:

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref _remainingLinks, links.Count)`
```

---

The `links` argument isn't being written from other threads while `ProcessLinks` is running, is it?

Comment: +1 for your pick up on the logic bug, I almost certainly would have missed that.